# Map to hold multiple sets of key and values

Tags: hashmap

I have a map1 which holds the information as 
    [40256942,6] [60246792,5]

Now that I want to prepare a map2 that holds information such as

```
itemNo, 40256942
qty, 6


itemNo, 60246792
qty, 5
```

to prepare final information as json

```
“partialArticlesInfo”: [{itemNo:”40256942”, availQty:”6”}, {itemNo:”60246792”, availQty:”5”}]
```

I am trying to iterate map1 to retrieve values and set that against the key. But I am getting only one entry which is last one. Is there any way , I get the new map with entries such as mentioned above

```
Map<String, String> partialArticlesInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
Map<String, String> partialArticlesTempMap = null;
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : partialStockArticlesQtyMap.entrySet())
{
    partialArticlesTempMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    partialArticlesTempMap.put("itemNo",entry.getKey());
    partialArticlesTempMap.put("availQty",entry.getValue());
    partialArticlesInfo.putAll(partialArticlesTempMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java (I'm assuming you're using Java, in the future it would be helpful to specify that) and every other language I know of, a map holds mappings between keys and values. Only one mapping is allowed per key. In your "map2", the keys are "itemNo" and "availQty". So what is happening is that your for loop sets the values for the first entry, and then is overwriting them with the data from the second entry, which is why that is the only one you see. Look at [Java - Map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) and [Map - Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for more info.

I don't understand why you are trying to put the data into a map, you could just put it straight into JSON with something like this:

```
JSONArray partialArticlesInfo = new JSONArray();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : partialStockArticlesQtyMap.entrySet()) {
    JSONObject stockEntry = new JSONObject();
    stockEntry.put("itemNo", entry.getKey());
    stockEntry.put("availQty", entry.getValue());

    partialArticlesInfo.put(stockEntry);
}

JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
root.put("partialArticlesInfo",partialArticlesInfo);
```

This will take "map1" (partialStockArticlesQtyMap in your code) and create a JSON object exactly like your example - no need to have map2 as an intermediate step. It loops over each entry in map1, creates a JSON object representing it and adds it to a JSON array, which is finally added to a root JSON object as "partialArticlesInfo".

The exact code may be slightly different depending on which JSON library you are using - check the docs for the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brendan. Another solution would be otherwise to store in the Set or List objects like the following.

```
class Item {
    Long itemNo;
    int quantity;

      public int hashCode() {
        Long.hashCode(itemNo) + Integer.hashCode(quantity);
      }

      public int equals(Object other) {
        other instanceOf Item && other.itemNo == this.itemNo && other.quantity = this.quantity;
      }
    }
}
```

then you can use the JsonArray method described by him to get the Json string in output

This means that adding new variables to the object won't require any more effort to generate the Json